# Ansible task has problems running on delegated host when filename matches hostname

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a playbook in which on of the tasks within is to copy template files to a specific server with delegate_to: named "grover"

The inventory list with servers of consequence here is:  bigbird, grover, oscar

These template files MUST have a name that matches each server's hostnames, and the delegate server grover also must have it's own instance of said file.  This template copy operation should only take place if the file does not already exist.  /tmp/grover pre-exists on server grover, and it needs to remain unaltered by the playbook run.

Eventually in addition to /tmp/grover on server grover, after the run there should also exist:  /tmp/bigbird and /tmp/oscar also on server grover.

The problem I'm having is that when the playbook runs without any conditionals, it does function, but then it also clobbers/overwrites /tmp/grover which is unacceptable.

BUT, if I add tasks in previous plays to pre-check for these files, and then a conditional at the template play to skip grover if the file already exists, it not only skips grover, but it skips every other server that would be run on grover for that play as well.  If I try to set it to run on every other server BUT grover, it will still fail because the delegate server is grover and that would be skipped.

Here is the actual example code snipits, playbook is running on all 3 servers due to host pattern:

```
- hosts: bigbird:grover:oscar

   - name: File clobber check.
     stat:
       path: /tmp/{{ansible_hostname}}
     register: clobber_check
     delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
     with_items:
       - "{{ grover }}"

   - name: Copy templates to grover.
     template:
       backup: yes
       src: /opt/template
       dest: /tmp/{{ansible_hostname}}
       group: root
       mode: "u=rw,g=rw"
       owner: root
     delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
     with_items:
       - "{{ grover }}"
     when: ( not clobber_check.stat.exists ) and ( clobber_check is defined )
```

If I run that, and /tmp/grover exists on grover, then it will simply skip the entire copy play because the conditional failed on grover.  Thus the other servers will never have their /tmp/bigbird and /tmp/oscar templates copied to grover due to this problem.

Lastly, I'd like to avoid ghetto solutions like saving a backup of grover's original config file, allowing the clobber, and then copying the saved file back as the last task.

I must be missing something here, I can't have been the only person to run into this scenario.  Anyone have any idea on how to code for this?

Comment: Start with removing unnecessary `with_items`...

Comment: @Konstantin Suvorov:  Thanks!  This is actually the answer, though I do not know how to make it so as it was a comment.  The moment I used actual inventory hostnames it started working as expected.  But it's a bit disappointing that I can't assign variables properly to a group and have them referenced for each host in that group like I was hoping to.  It means I'll have to set up a lot more tasks now, but I suppose that's only a minor detail.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is to remove the unnecessary with_items in the code.  While with_items used as it is does allow you to delegate_to a host pattern group, it also makes it so that variables can't be defined/assigned properly to the hosts within that group either.

Defining a single host entity for delegate_to fixes this issue and then the tasks execute as expected on all hosts defined.

Konstantin Suvorov should get the credit for this, as he was the original answer-er.

Additionally, I am surprised that Ansible doesn't allow for easy delegation to a group of hosts.  There must be reasons they didn't allow it.